# What expression > mean in sentence (python)?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

What is the type of output here?:

```
H2 = np.random.rand(*H1.shape) < p   ## p= 0.60    60%
```

Comment: That numpy expression creates a Boolean array with a share of `p` True values (and `1 - p` False).

Comment: @user7138814 can you give me more details ?  with example

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but not of the ones linked. He is asking what the `<` operator means in this context, not the `*` operator

Answer (score 2):

```
In [489]: x = np.random.rand(2,3)
In [490]: x
Out[490]: 
array([[ 0.09070037,  0.27653004,  0.14790416],
       [ 0.38391008,  0.1477435 ,  0.63524601]])
```

to find elements that are less than .5:

```
In [491]: x<.5   
Out[491]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was "What is the type of output here". The output will be a boolean (True or False) since it's comparing the result of `np.random.rand(*H1.shape)` with `p`. If `p` is bigger than `np.random.rand(*H1.shape)` `H2` will be True. Otherwise `H2` will be False(if `np.random.rand(*H1.shape)` is equal or smaller than `p`).